# Invalid argument when downloading files with wget

Tags: wget

I am attempting to download a set of files from an online database, which requires the use of wget. The shell script being used works on one of my computers, but I want to make it run on a different device, and therein lies the problem. For whatever reason, when executing the script, it gives me the following output:

```
--2021-07-21 12:03:12--  https://archive.eso.org/downloadportalapi/calibrationxml/672f7dfa-65b6-4117-aaf5-9eb2fd4d8759/GRAVI.2017-06-29T02:59:55.346_raw2master.xml
Resolving archive.eso.org (archive.eso.org)... 134.171.46.246
Connecting to archive.eso.org (archive.eso.org)|134.171.46.246|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: 3484 (3.4K) [application/octet-stream]
GRAVI.2017-06-29T02:59:55.346_raw2master.xml: Invalid argument

Cannot write to 'GRAVI.2017-06-29T02:59:55.346_raw2master.xml’ (Success).
```

Instead of writing a line describing where it is being saved as/to, it instead outputs "Invalid argument" and I'm not sure why. Both devices are running the same version of wget and the script used on both devices is identical. I also have plenty of disk space, so that isn't an issue either. If you want to look at the shell script, it is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iiB8ecH5hStH29LlUh1OhfKbq-1lpZU9/view?usp=sharing).

**EDIT:** Here are the outputs of

`mount`

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/keegan/LaCie type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1001,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

and `df -h`

```
/dev/sdb2/      9.1T   14G  9.1T   1% /media/keegan/LaCie
```

as requested in the comments.

Comment: The usual practice is to add script in the question. And google drive do not permit access to the file

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix & Linux. Can you add the wget line with its options specifically here? I know you've linked to the script, but the direct line will help contributors get started.

Comment: Also - can we safely assume you are wget'ing to a Linux/unix box? Can you add information about the file system it is attempting to write the file to?

Comment: Okay, it appears that the issue arises from wget-ing the files directly to an external hard drive, as I can run the script successfully on the integrated harddrive of the computer. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I am working with a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04) in both cases.

In addition, I adjusted the google drive link, you should be able to view it now. I wanted to avoid adding the script directly in the question as it is rather lengthy, but I can do so if you request.

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount` and `df -h` that refer to the external drive?

Comment: Done, anything else you need me to provide?

Comment: No, I think that should clarify the question. The `:` is not allowed on exFAT filesystems, although it is allowed on the linux-standard `ext2/3/4` filesystems. That is likely why it works on your internal drive (I didn't ask for the `mount` output of that one, but you can probably verify if that is an `ext` filesystem), but not the external one.

Comment: So theoretically, if I was to change the filesystem of the external harddrive to say NTFS or something, that might solve the problem? Or is that a bad idea regardless, due to other reasons?

Comment: NTFS also doesn't allow the `:`. You could change it to `ext4` instead, but it seems you want to exchange data with the windows world, so an on-the-fly file renaming seems to be the only choice here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127762/discussion-between-azog-and-adminbee).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create the file on a file system where the name contains illegal characters (the `:`). As you state in your edit, the file is to be created on an `exFAT` file system. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) on `exFAT` explicitly states:

> Allowed characters in filenames: all Unicode characters **except** `U+0000` (`NUL`) through `U+001F` (`US`), `/` (slash), `\` (backslash), **`:` (colon)**, `*` (asterisk), `?` (question mark), `"` (quote), `<` (less than), `>` (greater than) and `|` (pipe)

To verify, try to create the file with another command:

```
touch GRAVI.2017-06-29T02:59:55.346_raw2master.xml
```

If that is the cause, either use another file system, or use another name.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there shouldn't be any issues with the script, since it works fine "as is" on another device, and now also on the integrated harddrive of the computer in question. The problem seems to be linked to trying to download the files directly to an external harddrive, for whatever reason.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, I can download individual files using ```curl``` and a bit of a workaround, but I would like to avoid needing to rewrite the scripts, which are pre-generated by the database when i make a download request.

Answer (score 1):

As told before, there are some character limitations in the target file system (exFAT). Therefore you should use `--restrict-file-names=windows` option for `wget`. That converts problematic characters in the target file names and directory names.

Comment: Solved problem for me, thanks!